# Generate string lexicographically larger than input

Tags: c++, string, std

Given an input string `A`, is there a concise way to generate a string `B` that is lexicographically larger than `A`, i.e. `A < B == true`?

My raw solution would be to say:

```
B = A;
++B.back();
```

but in general this won't work because:

1. `A` might be empty
2. The last character of `A` may be close to wraparound, in which case the resulting character will have a smaller value i.e. `B < A`.
3. Adding an extra character every time is wasteful and will quickly in unreasonably large strings.

So I was wondering whether there's a standard library function that can help me here, or if there's a strategy that scales nicely when I want to start from an arbitrary string.

Comment: What is the answer you want when `A` is, in fact, empty?

Comment: @cigien Any answer that yields `A < B` is acceptable. A good answer would avoid "spending" the available range in a way that demands subsequent calls to add a character to the input string. I've posted my current solution as a dummy handling of common cases (I'm not happy with it yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can duplicate A into B then look at the final character. If the final character isn't the final character in your range, then you can simply increment it by one.

Otherwise you can look at last-1, last-2, last-3. If you get to the front of the list of chars, then append to the length.

Comment: Aha, so in my implementation I forgot to utilize more than the last character as a means to "increase" the string value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my dummy solution:

```cpp
std::string make_greater_string(std::string const &input)
{
    std::string ret{std::numeric_limits<
                    std::string::value_type>::min()};
 
    if (!input.empty())
    {
        if (std::numeric_limits<std::string::value_type>::max() 
            == input.back())
        {
            ret = input + ret;
        }   
        else
        {   
            ret = input;
            ++ret.back();
        }   
    }
   
    return ret;
}
```

Ideally I'd hope to avoid the explicit handling of all special cases, and use some facility that can more naturally handle them. Already looking at the answer by @JosephLarson I see that I could increment more that the last character which would improve the range achievable without adding more characters.

And here's the refinement after the suggestions in this post:

```cpp
std::string make_greater_string(std::string const &input)
{
    constexpr char minC = ' ', maxC = '~';
    // Working with limits was a pain, 
    // using ASCII typical limit values instead.
    
    std::string ret{minC};
 
    auto rit = input.rbegin(); 
    while (rit != input.rend())
    {
        if (maxC == *rit)
        {
            ++rit;
            if (rit == input.rend())
            {
                ret = input + ret;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ret = input;
            ++(*(ret.rbegin() + std::distance(input.rbegin(), rit)));
            break;
        }
    }
   
    return ret;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c435c6f4bdf5d6a)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the string and append some letters - this will produce a lexicographically larger result.

```
    B = A + "a"
```

Comment: In the question, I mention in (3): `Adding an extra character every time is wasteful and will quickly in unreasonably large strings`